# Are there active (as of 2020) developments in liquid-fuel tank technology?

Tags: materials, engineering, mass-fraction, tanks, development

This question was broken off from previous mega-question located [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/40917/can-you-help-me-fill-in-the-gaps-in-my-liquid-fuel-rocket-propellant-tank-techno).

I am aware of the broad liquid fuel tank types:

- V-2-style steel fuselage
- Integral steel
- Integral aluminum (with varying types of construction--waffle/isogrid/stringer sidewalls and separate/common bulkheads)
- Carbon-composite

Are any new tank types being developed? Perhaps by CNSA, Blue Origin or ULA?

Comment: much better, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The in-development Prime launcher from Orbex has an uncommon arrangement:

> One key aspect of propane is that it remains liquid at cryogenic temperatures. That enabled a “coaxial tank” design for Prime where a central tube of propane is surrounded by an outer tank of liquid oxygen, creating structural mass savings in the rocket.

(From [Space News](https://spacenews.com/orbex-stakes-claim-to-european-smallsat-launch-market/) )

Others sources say the common-temperature LOX-LPr wall is carbon composite. I haven’t seen a mention of the outer wall.

Comment: Very interesting and thank you for the source! Seems similar in design but different in purpose to the tank-in-a-tank I believe SpaceX is developing.

Comment: The key aspect is that both propane and oxygen are liquid between -187.6 and -183 °C. Below -187.7 °C propane is solid.

Comment: The fill processing for those tanks will require careful control to avoid LPr freezing or blowing off a bunch of LOX. Perhaps there are good SE questions in that area?